# How to fix apt-get: command not found on AWS EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Amazon EC2 instance and am trying to install packages using `apt-get`, but I am getting the following error:

```bash
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Ubuntu comes with `apt`, so it should be there. How do I fix this?

Comment: it's really strange. i haven't experienced any problem. Do you use the right command? Can you write the full command you typed?

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential git scons

Comment: What AMI Id? Is it public image?

Comment: Try to do this: `sudo su`, then `apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git scons`

Answer (score 468):

Try replacing `apt-get` with `yum` as Amazon Linux based AMI uses the `yum` command instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: this would be so much better than the nerd-kings closing the question.  `apt-get` doesn't work?  type `yum` instead.

Comment: Hey @Pat841 , mark this as the answer

Comment: what is AMI?. What is the difference between AMI linux and ubuntu

Comment: yum doesn't have the packages I need to install........ soooooo

Comment: Same here, yum does not support the package I need (`gfortran`). What to do?

Answer (score 23):

I guess you are actually using  Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1 instead of Ubuntu Server 12.x reason why you don't have apt-get tool installed.

Comment: Happening with UBUNTU Server also.

Comment: Considering the packages I need aren't available with yum. This seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 5):

Check with "uname -a" and/or "lsb_release -a" to see which version of Linux you are actually running on your AWS instance. The default Amazon AMI image uses YUM for its package manager.

Answer (score 4):

please, be sure your connected to a ubuntu server, I Had the same problem but I was connected to other distro, check the AMI value in your details instance, it should be something like

```
AMI: ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20130411.1
```

hope it helps