# Why are Docker build commands running so slow in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, system-administration

EB was complaining that my build was timing out, so I ssh'd into an instance and decided to run `docker build` myself to see what was happening.  Every step, even something as simple as a `mkdir` takes ages to run.  Even a `WORKDIR` stalls for at least a minute or two before executing.

On my local machine these are instant.  What is going on?

Answer (score 8):

Same issue here with an Ubuntu machine running on AWS. Turns out the the key to the solution was switching from devicemapper to aufs storage backend.

First, run the following command to figure out which storage backend your currently use:

`docker info | grep Storage`

If it says `devicemapper`, you probably found the reason for the slowness.

Here is the prodecure for switching to the aufs backend in Ubuntu, taken from [here](http://www.danstutzman.com/blog):

1. `sudo apt-get install -y -q linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`
2. `sudo service docker restart`

Note that you will have to rebuild all your existing images / containers, as they will be wiped when you switch to aufs.

Comment: amazing. it's now a thousand times faster, you saved my day.

Comment: Take note: Amazon Linux based AMI uses the yum command instead of apt-get. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045262/how-to-fix-apt-get-command-not-found-on-aws-ec2

Comment: What's the package name for AWS linux?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to know you are facing this issue.
Elastic Beanstalk environment creation involves creation of lots of resources like autoscaling group, EC2 instances, security groups, Elastic Load Balancer etc. After that software is installed on your beanstalk instances. I am assuming you are only talking about the slowness of software installation (docker build) on beanstalk.

If you just run mkdir that should not be very slow. It should be reasonably fast.

However if you think that docker build overall is running very slow that could be because of IO intensive operations.

One thing you can try is using [EBS provisioned IOPs with Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/09/16/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-ebs-general-purpose-ssd/).
Read more about SSD instances [here](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ssd-backed-elastic-block-storage/).

Can you try launching a new environment with SSD instances and see if docker build is still slow? If you can show an example dockerfile that takes a long time to build, I can try it out.

Comment: Either way a simple `RUN mkdir ~/asd` takes a very long time.  This should have nothing to do with EBS boot-related things.  I doubt that the FS is really the blocking factor, as I can run `apt-get` and it can fetch things very quickly.

Comment: Also the base docker image your dockerfile contains needs to be downloaded (which can easily be several 100MBs). This needs to be downloaded on each EC2 instance for the first time. Do you think that is causing the initial slowness? You can run `docker images` to see what images are currently being downloaded.

Comment: These are RUN commands.  These happen WAY after the initial image is downloaded.

Comment: If its just the RUN command that is slow then it may be something with the docker image ... Is it possible for you to put up some sample Dockerfile that I could use to repro the problem?

Comment: It could be... it runs very quickly on my local machine, and my local machine.  My instances are medium c1 instances -- pretty similar specs to my laptop.  I am on MacOS and building via Boot2Docker, so it should be much more performant than my machine.

Comment: What instance type are you running this on? I started testing then using Docker on Beanstalk recently, and found out much to my dismay that those small `t1.micro` instances could not handle a lot. Once I switched to even t2.small, building the Docker container went from about 10 minutes to 2 minutes.