# Best way to automate installation of psql on a machine?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out a way to install `psql` on an AWS ec2 machine via a shell script. The machine will be spun up every hour, and it won't be the same one every time. What are the exact commands to install `psql`? I've tried `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client` but that didn't work. The error I got was: `sudo: apt-get: command not found`.

Comment: You're installing it as usual depending on the operating system which you use. Which one it is?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Apt-Get in AWS EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14045262/55075)